# Sorting with higher order functions: Giving precedence to one element

Tags: swift, sorting, higher-order-functions

With an unordered array of Ints as such:

```
let numbers = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
```

Is it possible in Swift, using .sorted { }, to order the array with one item prioritised and placed in the first index of the array. So instead of returning [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] we could get [3, 1, 2, 4, 5]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a function like this :

```
func sort(_ array: [Int], prioritizing n: Int) -> [Int] {
    var copy = array
    let pivot = copy.partition { $0 != n }
    copy[pivot...].sort()
    return copy
}
```

Which uses the [`partition(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition) function.

You could use it like so:

```
let numbers = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
let specialNumber = 3
sort(numbers, prioritizing: specialNumber) //[3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Here are some test cases :

```
sort([3, 3, 3], prioritizing: 3)           //[3, 3, 3]
sort([9, 4, 1, 5, 2], prioritizing: 3)     //[1, 2, 4, 5, 9]
```

---

Here an alternative solution that uses `sorted(by:)` only :

```
let numbers = [4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
let vipNumber = 3
let result = numbers.sorted {
    ($0 == vipNumber ? Int.min : $0) < ($1 == vipNumber ? Int.min : $1)
}
print(result)                              //[3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: It could be better with an array extension

Comment: Thanks, this helps. partition(by:) is not something I've come across... will take a look

Comment: @Zaphod I feel like it would just pollute the array namespace for a not so common use case. A [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) (with multiple levels of priority) would be more of an appropriate data structure, and a more generic solution to this *problem*.

Comment: The idea was to be more generic, because this kind of behavior could be useful for other types than `Int`. But it was just a proposal.